# Remove duplicates from list of tuples based on value at certain index

Tags: python, tuples

I have a dictionary, and for each key I have a list of tuples. The length of the list varies, but every tuple has 4 entries. Heres an example of one key

```
genes = {'Tcea1': [
('995', '057', '551', '613'), 
('825', '912', '541', '683'), 
('541', '683', '821', '877'), 
('825', '912', '538', '683'), 
('538', '683', '821', '877'), 
('489', '584', '551', '613')]}
```

What I want to do is remove duplicates. But the only part that I care about is index position 1 and 2. So in the above example I want ('541', '683', '821', '877') and ('538', '683', '821', '877') removed because index 1 is 683 for both and index 2 is 821 for both. So ideally the output would be

```
genes = {'Tcea1': [
('995', '057', '551', '613'), 
('825', '912', '541', '683'), 
('825', '912', '538', '683'), 
('489', '584', '551', '613')]}
```

This has me stumped. Below is the closest I can get. The following code will just remove one of the tuples but I want both gone

```
seen = set()
seen_add = seen.add
genes['Tcea1'] = [x for x in genes['Tcea1'] if tuple(x[1:3]) not in seen and not seen_add(tuple(x[1:3]))]
```

Edit: I need to preserve order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
from collections import Counter

def selectUnique(x):
    count = Counter((i[1], i[2]) for i in x)
    out = [i for i in x if count[(i[1], i[2])] == 1]
    return out
```

A Counter is just a dictionary that maps keys to frequencies.

Comment: can Counter be used with lists as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to detect duplicates, and then filter based on it:

```
from collections import Counter
def myfilter(list_of_tuples):
  key = lambda tpl: tpl[1:3]
  counter = Counter(key(t) for t in list_of_tuples)
  return [ t for t in list_of_tuples if counter[key(t)] <= 1 ]
```

And apply to your dict like this:

```
new_genes = { k: myfilter(v) for k,v in genes.items() }
```

This solution also preserves order.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest solution is

```
    { k: [ a for a in genes[k] if len([ b for b in genes[k] if b[1:3] == a[1:3]  ]) < 2  ] for k in genes }
```

It should be good if the lists are relatively short.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is the simplest way

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter(x[1:3] for x in genes['Tcea1'])
>>> filter(lambda x: counter[x[1:3]] == 1, genes['Tcea1'])
[('995', '057', '551', '613'), ('825', '912', '541', '683'), ('825', '912', '538', '683'), ('489', '584', '551', '613')]
```